# Error in groovy script while trying to add xpath assertion

Tags: excel, xpath, groovy, soapui, assertion

I am getting below exception while trying to execute below code:

> missing property exception

Code in groovy script for adding xpath assertion into a test case.

Is there any possible solution to solve the error please?

It has test suite name as "ManagePostpayInsurance_1_0" and test step name as "getInsuranceDetails_1_FTC_005".

```
log.info("Testing Start")
TSName = "ManagePostpayInsurance_1_0"
StepName = "getInsuranceDetails_1_FTC_005"
project.getTestSuiteList().each {
    if(it.name == TSName) {
        TS = it.name
        it.getTestCaseList().each {
            TC =it.name
            def asserting = project.getTestSuiteByName(TS).getTestCaseByName(TC).getTestStepByName(StepName).getAssertionByName("XPath Match")
            if (asserting instanceof com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.XPathContainsAssertion) {
                project.getTestSuiteByName(TS).getTestCaseByName(TC)getTestStepByName(StepName).removeAssertion(asserting)
            }
            def assertion = project.getTestSuiteByName(TS).getTestCaseByName(TC)getTestStepByName(StepName).addAssertion("XPath Match")
            assertion.path = "declare namespace cor='http://soa.o2.co.uk/coredata_1';\ndeclare namespace man='http://soa.o2.co.uk/managepostpayinsurancedata_1';\ndeclare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';\n"
            assertion.expectedContent = "200"   
        }
    }

}
log.info("Testing Stop")
```

Thanks in advance

This is the error log which I am able to see:

> Fri Nov 24 10:16:40 IST 2017:ERROR:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: project for class: Script13
>      groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: project for class: Script13
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
>       at Script13.run(Script13.groovy:7)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:90)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve below error

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: project for class: Script13

by adding below statement at the *top of your script*

```
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `.` dot at `getTestCaseByName(TC)getTestStepByName(StepName)`.